# How to open a xaml page as a dialog in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone app on windows phone 8.0. How to show xaml page as a dialog ? In android they have given an option to select a Theme.Dialog which makes the android activity to appear as a dialog. But how to do this in windows phone 8.0?

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what you are trying to do. What code do you have so far? Can you clarify with screenshots or place it in the context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Suppose I have a registration page which is designed using xaml (Registration.xaml). And the code behind it is (Registration.xaml.cs). Now this xaml file I just want it to appear as a dialog. Is it possible in windows phone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a popup control. Add xaml page that you want to open as child of popup.

```
PopUp mypopup = new PopUp();
mypopup.child = new Uri("Mypage.xaml",Urikind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: I am unable to get the namespace of PopUp. I used Windows.UI.PopUps namespace but it is giving me error.

Comment: First install wptoolkit in your project. Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager console. In Console type the following command "Install-Package WPtoolkit". Now you'll be able to use popup control in your project. Thanks